# Excel PowerQuery - Dimension to Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I've got following 2 Tables:

```
 Date   Name  Value
1.1.19    A     11
1.1.19    B     54
1.1.19    C    234
2.1.19    A    346
2.1.19    B    654
3.1.19    A    156
3.1.19    B    6432
3.1.19    C    665
...
```

```
 Date   OtherName  Value
1.1.19      D       1
1.1.19      E       6
1.1.19      F       2
2.1.19      F       46
2.1.19      E       54
3.1.19      D       15
3.1.19      E       632
3.1.19      F       66
...
```

and i want to transform them into

```
 Date   Total Value  A.Value  B.Value  C.Value  D.Value  E.Value  F.Value
1.1.19     308         11       54       234       1        6        2
2.1.19     1100        346     654       0         0       54        46 
3.1.19     7966        156     6432      665       15      632       66
```

using Power Query in excel.
I tried multiple approaches including Joins, Table.AddColumn with Table.SelectRow and whatnot. I cant seem to find any combination of formulas that fit my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

1. Add 2 Tables to Power Query Editor as Queries:

[image]

2. Make 2 Tables' Title as the same and Append 2 Queries:

[image]

3. Select Name column- go to Transform tab- Pivot Column- Value Column select Value and Advanced options select Sum- Close and Load:

[image]

Comment: The OP also wants a `Total Value` column which you can get by adding a Number column with the Sum operation.  But suggest you edit the M-Code so as to include all columns except the `Date` column, in case new `Name`s appear in the future.